# Controls for Youtube Chromeless Player In Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube, controls, chromeless

I'm tearing my hair out trying to add controls such as pause and volume to my Chromeless Youtube Player in Flash with actionscript 3, tried working with the reference that google provide but it still doesn't work. Here's what I tried, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
function pauseVideo() {
if (player) {
player.pauseVideo();
}
}


pauseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pauseVideo);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How I understand you are trying to integrate youtube's player into your application. Take a look at [this example](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/ytplayer/actionscript3/com/google/youtube/examples/AS3Player.as) it may help you and check with the documentation if you are loading correctly their player and it's fully loaded when you are trying to access it, [first example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#Examples)

**I would like to help you more but I don't know how you instantiate the player*